# How to query for formatted data in MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

How can I query for improperly formatted data in MYSQL?

For example, if I have the following data in my table:

```
1.John Doe
2.john doe
3.JOHN DOE
4.joHn DoE.
```

I'm looking for a query that would return rows 2, 3, and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,name FROM `Table1` 
WHERE `name` NOT REGEXP BINARY '([A-Z]{1,1}[a-z]+ [A-Z]{1,1}[a-z]+)$';
```

Output

```
id  name
2   john doe
3   JOHN DOE
4   joHn DoE.
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3092b3/75

Answer (score 0):

To ensure data integrity it is a better practice to store names/surnames/street names/addresses etc in separate fields and without any capitalization. For display purposes, you can apply capitalization. This way you will save some trouble figuring out if John = john = jOhn.

Run the following to normalize values:

```
 UPDATE Table1 SET name = LOWER(name)
```